# Understanding glxinfo error

Tags: 18.04, ssh, xorg, opengl, xserver

My env is Ubuntu 18.04, headless server.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

If I connect via `ssh`:

```
glxinfo
Error: unable to open display

echo $DISPLAY prints nothing.
```

If I connect via `ssh -Y`:

```
glxinfo
name of display: localhost:10.0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20

echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

In both cases:

```
ps aux | grep X

root      1044  0.0  0.0  70412  4368 ?        S    янв29   0:00 sudo X :9 -config /root/run_x/dummy-1920x1080.conf
root      1061  0.0  0.0 1716624 50392 ?       Sl   янв29   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :9 -config /root/run_x/dummy-1920x1080.conf
root     25639  0.0  0.0 276668 46856 tty7     Ssl+ янв29   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

`ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo`

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea151f000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3bb7ee4000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f3bb7bac000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3bb77bb000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f3bb758a000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f3bb72d4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3bb70b5000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3bb6e8d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3bb6c89000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3bb837f000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3bb6a85000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3bb687f000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f3bb666a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3bb6462000)
```

What does this error `X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)` mean?

Comment: What are you connecting to using ssh? Is it Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Yes, it's Ubuntu 18.04, headless server.

Comment: Why would you run glxinfo on a headless server?

Comment: @Pilot6 Because I need to run some app that use OpenGL, so I need to check if my env is ok, is running glxinfo is a good way to check OpenGL setup is ok?

Comment: It lookslike the server doesn;t have a graphics adapter. So you can't run this kind of applications there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Raspberry Pi4 aarch64, however the graphic adapter is there.

Comment: @mrgloom Did you end up figuring out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Please specify the "name" of the available display to connect, :9 in the case above, and have it defined before running the glxinfo command, something like: `DISPLAY=:9 /usr/bin/glxinfo -v -B`